# Prevent NodeExpand Event in PrimeNg

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am Creating Web Application with Angular using the [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) UI Framework.
I use the [TreeTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable) Component.
The TreeTable Component has an Event called 'onNodeExpand' which will be triggerd once a node gets Expandend. 
Now comes my question: 

Is there a way to prevent this onNodeExpand to occur so when you click on the expand Icon nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="files" [columns]="cols" (onNodeExpand)="onNodeExpand($event)">

in component.ts file read the event and set the expanded property false;

onNodeExpand(event) {
    event.node.expanded=false;
  }
```